# Write multiple sheets in excel file using ByteScout Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have several DataTable objects and I want to write them to one excel file but various sheets.

I'm using [bytescout.spreadsheet](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html) to work with excel files.

How can I write multiple table sheets to excel file using this tool and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manual: http://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutxls_working_with_worksheets_in_xls_document.html

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet;
namespace Worksheets
{

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    // Create new Spreadsheet
        Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet();
      // Add worksheets
        Worksheet worksheet1 = document.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo worksheet 1");
        Worksheet worksheet2 = document.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo worksheet 2");
      // Get worksheet by name
        Worksheet worksheetByName = document.Workbook.Worksheets.ByName("Demo worksheet 2");
      // Set cell values
        worksheet1.Cell(0, 0).Value = "This is Demo worksheet 1";
        worksheetByName.Cell(0, 0).Value = "This is Demo worksheet 2";
        // Save document
        document.SaveAs("Worksheets.xls");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it when I tried to write a DataTable object to the file but I can't open the file. When I try open the file I get an error that the file is corrupted.

Comment: hey could u tell me how to open existing spreadsheet using Bytescout. Their tutorials do not match their current api.

Comment: @MohitShah contact bytescout technical support - responses are pretty fast even for non-registered users. and check this sample https://github.com/bytescout/ByteScout-SDK-SourceCode/blob/master/Spreadsheet%20SDK/C%23/Read%20XLSX%20(Office%202007)%20files/Program.cs